# randomized number in src iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Today I'm working on a project. I've to make a iframe with randomized numbers in the source, like:

```
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+{num}+"','"+{num}+"&hl=es&z=14&amp;output=embed"
```

The num is already a randomized number, but if I want to print it in the iframe it doesn't work then.
Do you guys have some advice?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
src={"https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+num+"','"+num+"&hl=es&z=14&amp;output=embed"}
```

Comment: No it doens't work, he says identifier expected by the +

Comment: I didn't get it. can you explain?

Comment: Sorry I've not looked good at the {} by the src.... he is working thank you

Comment: @user12380607 if you think this answer helped you, then mark this answer as the correct answer, please

Comment: @user12380607 if you think this answer helped you, then mark this answer as the correct answer, please